# How does one update a file by line number in powershell?

Tags: powershell, replace, split, line

all,

I am trying to update a line in config file with powershell and I can't seem get it working properly...

I have this file: config.ini

```
version.clients.latest.location=.\
version.clients.latest.classpath=My.jar
version.clients.latest.mainclass=gui.Launch

version.clients.latest.jreLocation=C:\home\user\agent\install_master\Deploy\Admin\..\1AOpenJRE\jre1.8.0_342\jre8
version.clients.latest.jre.options=-Xmx256m -Dcrow.library.path=.\crow\crow-native -Dcrow.runtime.path=.\crow\cre\ -Denv.global.clp.enable=false
#version.clients.latest.xre.isUsed=true
#version.clients.latest.xre.version=2.2
#version.clients.latest.xre.location=L:\Cross-Projects\2.2\2.5\xre
version.client.latest.xre.isUsed=true
version.client.latest.xre.version=2.2
version.client.latest.xre.location=./xre
version.client.latest.xulWrapper.dllFile=./xre/XULWrapper.dll
version.client.latest.xre.cache.isEnabled=true
version.client.latest.xre.cache.isShared=true
version.client.latest.jreOptions=-Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false
```

and I want to update this line

```
version.clients.latest.jreLocation=C:\home\user\agent\install_master\Deploy\Admin\..\1AOpenJRE\jre1.8.0_342\jre8
```

with a new path... Like so...

```
version.clients.latest.jreLocation=..\..\..\1AOpenJRE\jre1.8.0_342\jre8
```

and I made this script

```
# Config
$CfgFile = ".\cfg\cfg.ini"
$SearchString = "version.clients.latest.jreLocation="

$ConfigContent = Get-Content "$CfgFile"
$ConfigSelectLine =  Get-Content -Path "$CfgFile" | Select-String $SearchString
$LineNum = $ConfigSelectLine.LineNumber

$key = $ConfigSelectLine -Split("=")[0]
$filePath = $ConfigSelectLine -Split("..")[1]

$ImportantPath = $filePath -Split("..")[1]
$NewLine = 'version.clients.latest.jreLocation=..\..\..' + $ImportantPath

$ConfigContent[$LineNum] = "$NewLine" | Set-Content ".\cfg\cfg-test.ini"
```

and when I run it, I a output file with one line ...

```
version.clients.latest.jreLocation=..\..\..\
```

How do we split a string on ".."? and why is the entire file wiped out when I try to update the single line in the file by line number?

Cheers,

X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line doesn't do what you intend:

> `$ConfigContent[$LineNum] = "$NewLine" | Set-Content ".\cfg\cfg-test.ini"`

This saves the value of `$NewLine` *only* to file `.\cfg\cfg-test.ini`, and *then* stores the *output from the `Set-Content` call* in the element with index `$LineNum` of array `$ConfigContent` (and, unless you use `-PassThru`, `Set-Content produces *no* output).

While `($ConfigContent[$LineNum] = "$NewLine") | Set-Content ".\cfg\cfg-test.ini"` would - thanks to `(...)` - first update the array element and then pass the updated value through, you'd still only save *that element* to the file.

The problem with the splitting by `..` is simply due to calling `.Split('..')[1]` *twice*.
Replace:

```bash
$filePath = $ConfigSelectLine -Split("..")[1]

$ImportantPath = $filePath -Split("..")[1]
```

with:

```bash
$ImportantPath = $ConfigSelectLine -Split("..")[1]
```

Also, you should add the `-SimpleMatch` switch to your [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) call to ensure that your search term is used *literally*.

---

The immediate fix for the single-line-only result is to first update the array element and then send the updated array *as a whole* to the output file:

```bash
$ConfigContent[$LineNum] = $NewLine
Set-Content ".\cfg\cfg-test.ini" -Value $ConfigContent
```

Note the use of the `-Value` parameter rather than the pipeline, which speeds up the operation.

---

However, your code can be greatly streamlined, using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement:

```bash
$CfgFile = ".\cfg\cfg.ini"
$SearchString = "version.clients.latest.jreLocation="

$(
  switch -WildCard -File $CfgFile {
    "$SearchString*" {
       $prop, $value = $_ -split '=', 2
       "$prop=" + '..\..\..' + $value.Split('..')[1]
     }
    Default { $_ } # pass through
  }
) | Set-Content .\cfg\cfg-test.ini
```